# Is oscillating charge same thing as oscillating dipole?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, harmonic-oscillator

I was trying to do this problem from Griffith (Problem 11.22):

> A particle of mass $m$ and charge $q$ is attached to a spring with force constant $k$, hanging from the ceiling. Its equilibrium position is a distance $h$ above the floor. It is pulled down a distance $d$ below equilibrium and released, at time $t = 0$.
> Find the intensity on the floor.

Now, I can find a solution for this problem,just by googling, but the one I found starts as follows:

> This is an oscillating dipole with moment $p_0 = qd$ and $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$.

and textbook has already investigated this case.

My question is, shouldn't there be another charge as well , $-q$, oscillating too with this charge for us to say it is a oscillating dipole (under the usual approximatins)?
In the text, author considers this case.

Comment: You'll need to add an extra charge $q$ to counter the effective charge $-q$ in your dipole approximation.

Answer (score 0):

The motion for this charge is $h-d\cos(\omega t)$, where $d, h, \omega$ as in the original post.  Let's assume the solution for the wanted electric field is $\vec{E}(t)$.

Now, a mirror charge of $-q$ about $h$ has motion $h+d\cos(\omega t)= h-d\cos(\omega t + \pi) = h-d\cos(\omega(t+\pi/\omega))$.  So the solution for a mirror charge is $-\vec{E}(t+\pi/\omega)$.

Now, let's assume you know the solution $\vec{E}_d(t)$ for an oscillating dipole whose amplitude is $qd$ downward with the same frequency.  Then
$$\vec{E}(t) - \vec{E}(t+\pi/\omega) = \vec{E}_d(t)$$
So from $\vec{E}_d$ you can try solve for $\vec{E}$, and hopefully it's some sinusoidal waveform which will make it easy to see the solution.

Comment: I got my answer from the comment by @LPZ.  Nevertheless, this answer may be helpful for some sanity check of solutions.

Comment: Also , there is no unique solution for E, since E+c is also solution.

Comment: There is no image charge.

Comment: JerroldFranklin, Chad K added another charge not because it was necessary but because if added, superposition of E's could give that of dipole.

Comment: The unecessary extra charge is wrong because it gives twice the dipole moment.          The dipole moment comes from a multipole expansion of any compact charge distribution without adding superfluous charges.

Answer (score 0):

You left out that Griffiths states "Under the usual assumptions,  $(d<<\lambda<< h)$."
$qd\sin(\omega t)$ is the oscillating dipole source.

Comment: Could you elaborate how those assumptions take care of lack of $-q$ charge?

Comment: Also, I meant the usual assumptions with "under usual approx"  but thats better